# ログインアカウントの追加画面: Facebook がはみ出ている

Tags: バグ, 完了, デザイン

URL: https://ja.stackoverflow.com/users/login-add?returnUrl=%2Fusers%2Fcurrent

[image: Facebook]

Google Chrome 37.0.2062.124 / Mac OS X 10.9.5 / Retina

Comment: デザインが混雑しているため、時間がかかります。しばらくお待ち下さい。

Answer (score 1):

2020/08/12 現在は以下の通り正常に表示されていますので、いったん [完了](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%e5%ae%8c%e4%ba%86) にしたいと思います。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]